# Swing Thread Callbacks

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Any suggestions on how I can cleanup the following code pattern that repeats multiple times in my app.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Do some work here
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // Update the Swing Interface to reflect the change
      }

    });
  }
}).start();
```

Basically there are two code blocks the section that does the work on another thread, and the code block that executes in the Swing UI Thread.

I'm pretty sure I can create a class to sub in these blocks, but I'm hoping there something in the Swing Library that makes this easier.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to throw something on the Event Dispatch Thread, that is the way to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at the [SwingWorker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker) framework

Comment: Swing worker uses a background thread.  Allain wants to put the action on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: Actually, the only portion I need to run in the Event Dispatch Thread is the portion *after* the main block has completed, and by overriding SwingWorker.done() in the SwingWorker class, I get that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The [Concurrency in Swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) tutorial is another good place to look. There's discussion about SwingWorker there, too.